# Cant import Vue library from Javascript file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, export

I have exported a Vue component library targeted as a library. But trying to import it does not work. I get the error `Cannot read property extend of undefined`.

It happens on the line where it tries to export Vuetify colorable. So one way to fix this may be exporting it without Vuetify and somehow use it as a dependency instead.

I **CANNOT** export it as an npm module so do not suggest that.

My build script:

```js
"build-bundle": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name test-component-library src/index2.js",
```

My index2.js:

```js
import TestComponent from './components/TestComponent/TestComponent' // Expansionheader
const FirstLibrary = {
    install (Vue) {
        Vue.component('test-component', TestComponent);
    }
};

// Automatic installation if Vue has been added to the global scope.
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.Vue) {
    window.Vue.use(FirstLibrary)
}

export default FirstLibrary;
```

Import is in index.html like:

```
<script src="test-component-library.umd.js"></script>
```

I tried both using the common and the umd build files. Both of them give errors. Can anyone help me resolve this? Or know a way to export the library without Vuetify?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Same issue here. I tried `--skip-plugins vuetify` when building the module but no change

Comment: Sadly not. What i ended up doing was export it with Vuetify and import the script file after Vue got imported. Because the reason it was going wrong was because Vue got imported after my script files which didnt work (obviously).